# How to limit the number of pagination links in Zend_Paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

When using Zend_Paginator, I don't want it to show me all the pagination links. Here's how I am implementing it:

```
  $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($result);
  $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
  $page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
  $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
  $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
  $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

Now it is showing me all the links. E.g. there are 100 records and 10 rows per page, so it will show me 1 to 10 links. **How can I have 5 links, 1 to 5?**
Like this:

```
"start"  "previous" 1  2  3  4  5  "Next"  "End"
```

**EDITED**

```
<!--Number page links-->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
    <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>">
            <span class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default"><?= $page; ?></span>
        </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" ><?= $page; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I change it so that it shows me only 5 links?

```
$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$paginator->setPageRange(5);
$this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!-- Numbered page links -->
    <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
        <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
        <?php if ($page <6): ?>
            <a href="<?= $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>"><span class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default"><?= $page; ?></span></a>
        <?php elseif($page <6): ?>
            <span class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default ui-state-disabled" ><?= $page; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$paginator->setPageRange(5);` works for me. However you may need to apply this feature in your paginator control.
This is what the page link section of my control looks like.

```
<!--Number page links-->
        <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
            <?php if ($page != $this->current) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array_merge($params,
                        array('page' => $page))) ?>">
                    <?php echo $page ?></a> |
            <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $page ?> |
                <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: my <!--Number page links--> look like this kindly see the edit

Answer (score 0):

this is a good one. By default, Zend Paginator sets the default to 10 as you've seen. But the way to override it is as follows:

```
$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($result);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$paginator->setPageRange(5);
$this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

You can find a bit more information in the [configuration methods for Zend Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.configuration.html)

Comment: I should have replied using your code sample as the basis of my code sample. sorry about that.

Comment: @sir what do you mean by <your configuration object> ??

Comment: that was my mistake. I should have started the example with:
$adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($result);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

Comment: kindly edit your answer plz bcox i changed my code but still getting 10 links